# Nexus 4 download issue

Tags: nexus-4, mobile-data

I own a nexus 4 and since then i am unable to download anything via 2g/3g.
I am able to download content only through wi-fi.
The same applies for PlayStore. I have even tried in safe mode.
I have tried to clear data of Download Manager and even Playstore but in vain
Please help.

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to download? Is it only through Google Play, or something else as well?

Comment: Any app from playstore and also general content like images,songs etc...The same can be accomplished via wi-fi.

Comment: This might be obvious, but did you pay your phone bill?

Comment: lol...I have paid..:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. It was related to my APN. My Access Point allowed only browsing. I changed it to another access point, and it worked!